# Npm/Yarn Not installing properly and giving issues

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg

```
node ./postinstall.js
```

ngrok - error unpacking binary Error: You cannot extract a file outside of the target path

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! @expo/ngrok@2.3.0 postinstall: `node ./postinstall.js`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the @expo/ngrok@2.3.0 postinstall script.

- OS: Windows 10
- node: 8.11.4
- npm: 6.4.0

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo npm i -g ngrok --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: You're a GOD! Neither cleaning cache or reinstalling NVM worked..

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** $ `npm cache clean --force`

**Step 2:** delete node_modules by $ `rm -rf node_modules` folder or delete it manually by going into the directory and right-click > delete.

**Step 3:** `npm install`

To start again, $ `npm start`

This worked for me. Hopes it works for you too.

Still if it is there, kindly check the error it displays in red and act accordingly. 
**Be careful when using rm -rf**. This error is specific to node.js environment. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

first delete the node module after that clear the cache and then install npm hope works for you.

Comment: Can you add what you need to do to do this?

Comment: first you have to delete a node module folder from your directory. Then clear the cache ($ npm cache clean --force). then install the npm( npm install ).